# Equivalent of NMI and B3 for multilabel extrinsic clustering evaluation metrics

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning, information-theory

Normalized Mutual Information (NMI) and B3 are used for extrinsic clustering evaluation metrics when each instance (sample) has only one label.

What are equivalent metrics when each instance (sample) has only one label?

For example, in first image, we see [apple, orange, pears], in second image, we see [orange, lime, lemon] and in third image, we see [apple], and in the forth image we see [orange]. Then, if put first image and last image in the one cluster it is good, and if put third and forth image in one cluster is bad.

Application: Many popular datasets for object detection or image segmentation have multi labels for each image. If we used this data for classification (not detection and not segmentation), we have multiple labels for each image.

Note: My task is unsupervised clustering, not supervised classification. I know that for supervised classification, we can use top-5 or top-10 score. But I do not know what will be in unsupervised clustering.

Answer (score 0):

If the multi-labels are still sparse, then you can use Element-centric similarity, Omega Index, or Overlapping NMI (I dont recommend the last, it has severe biases).  All three are implemented in the python package, [CluSim](https://github.com/Hoosier-Clusters/clusim).

If the multi-labels are dense, then you are into [fuzzy clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_classification) comparison.  There are several divergence measures for membership functions, including L1-norm, Euclidean distance, KL-divergence, but I'm not aware of a literature arguing for one method over another.